# iOS Concurrency issue: method returned before got the pedometer data

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, core-motion

like the code below, when I want to return a pedometer data through a method for some connivence, but the method returned earlier than the data be retrieved.I think this maybe a concurrency issue. How could I return the data in a right way for future use？Thx

```
 func queryPedometerTodayTotalData() -> Int {
     var pedometerDataOfToday: CMPedometerData?
        self.queryPedometerDataFromDate(NSDate.today()!, toDate: NSDate(), withHandler: { (pedometerData, error) in
            pedometerDataOfToday = pedometerData!
            print("this print after got data in a background thread:\(pedometerDataOfToday)")
        })
        print("This should print before last print, and there haven't got the data now: \(pedometerDataOfToday)")
    return pedometerDataOfToday
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about it being a concurrency issue. You should use the result inside the handler of the `queryPedometerDataFromDate`.
One way of achieving this would be to use a completion block for your `queryPedometerTodayTotalData` method instead of having it return a value, like this:

```
func queryPedometerTodayTotalData(completion:((CMPedometerData?)->())) {
    var pedometerDataOfToday: CMPedometerData?
    self.queryPedometerDataFromDate(NSDate.today()!, toDate: NSDate(), withHandler: { (pedometerData, error) in
        pedometerDataOfToday = pedometerData!
        completion(pedometerData)
    })
}

func testQueryPedometerTodayTotalData() {
    self.queryPedometerTodayTotalData { (data) in
        print(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx.I did so,It could print data correctly but how could I to return the data? `func testQueryPedometerTodayTotalData() -> CMPedometerData {
        var todayData: CMPedometerData?
        self.queryPedometerTodayTotalData { (data) in
            todayData = data
        }
        return todayData!
    }` <br> This gonna be crash again

Comment: You can't return it since it's asyncronous. You use it in the completion block. Instead of printing the data you can do whatever you need to with it.

Comment: So appreciate. I use another solution to deal it. But I really want to know why I couldn't get or return an asynchronous result? I used a instance variable to save the result in the block and return, could you please explain why it doesn't work, thx again

Answer (score 0):

It is a concurrency issue. `queryPedometerDataFromDate` is an asynchronous method. it executes the completion block whenever iOS deems it (which would usually be after it has retrieved the data) so that is why the 2nd print line prints first and doesnt return your result.

You need to either use the `pedometerData` from the completion block inside the completion block, or call a method/delegate that will handle the result of the completion block.